# Copy large github file into existing repo without downloading/cloning

Tags: git, github, version-control, pytorch

How to i add bin file associated to this repo https://github.com/graykode/gpt-2-Pytorch to my existing private repo without downloading/cloning?  There is a 500mb file that needs downloading to get the codebase to work that I need in my repo and don't want to download into my small hard disk during the cloning process.
It's a noob question but i'm at a complete loss as to how to proceed. Please be nice.

Comment: Visit each file directly on github, copy the text, create a new file locally, and paste the contents. Repeat until done. Or, you could clone the repo or download the code.

Comment: there's a very large file in said repo that I am avoiding to download into my small hard disk

Comment: Git does not work well with such large files, as you're discovering. Consider using [Git Large File Storage](https://git-lfs.github.com/).

Comment: Yes. Using LFS will require me to download/clone the repo. Is there a way to just add the file into my repo without having to clone said repo?

Comment: @Firefinch There is no large file in gpt-2-Pytorch.

Comment: @Firefinch Perhaps you're referring to downloading gpt2-pytorch_model.bin?

Comment: yes @Scgwern.  I should re edit the question. I need to download the bin file into my hard disk and don't have enough space to do so. I just need the thing in my repo

Comment: @Firefinch Sorry, I remembered Github doesn't allow files that large. I did discover that `curl` will upload files from stdin, so you can stream a file upload from a download with ``wget ... | curl --upload-file=-`. Might be useful another time.

Comment: thanks for your help @Scgwern et al. I've chosen to use lfs. It's quite straight forward to use. Salute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, sorry. [The maximum file size on Github is 100 MB](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/conditions-for-large-files). And for good reason, Git does not work well with large, binary files.

---

Simplest thing is to find a USB key or other external storage and use it as temporary space to store the file while you add it with [git-lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com/).

Or don't add the file to your repository. Download and cache it as part of your build process.

Comment: you are right. I just chose to go the lfs route and figure out the local hard disk issue when it becomes a problem